# kendo Image browser delete

Tags: image, kendo-ui, editor

I have implemented kendo editor within it i have implemented kendo image browser.
I have implemented it the way it is guided in documentation with same backend controller.

I have implemented kendo confirmation box for other functionality too. **I want kendo alert instead of javascript alert** for confirmation when one delete image. so I have capture the delete event and using event.stopPropagation I manage stop the default delete behaviour and implemented kendo confirm box. on its ok button i have called backend destroy method of controller to delete image using ajax.

Fortunately it is successfully deleted from backend **but from view side that is in image browser thumbnail it is not deleting**, after refreshing the  it goes from view side or remove from thumbnail . I have also try to manually delete the respective li it got deleted but as soon as I upload some new image that deleted li also comes up with deleted image although it has been deleted from backend.
Here is the code how I implemented image browser:

````
function createEditor(id)
        {
            //Kendo Editor for content
            $(id).kendoEditor({
                encoded: false,
                tools: [
                        "bold",
                        "italic",
                        "underline",
                        "strikethrough",
                ],
                imageBrowser: {
                    transport: {
                        read: "/ImageBrowser/Read",
                        destroy: {
                            url: '/ImageBrowser/Destroy',
                            type: "POST"
                        },
                        create: {
                            url: '/ImageBrowser/Create',
                            type: "POST"
                        },
                        thumbnailUrl: '/ImageBrowser/Thumbnail',
                        uploadUrl: '/ImageBrowser/Upload',
                        imageUrl:  "../Content/article/" + userId + "/{0}"
                    },
                }
            });

//On click of imagebrowser icon of editor
            $(".k-i-image").click(function () {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    // Attach a select handler to the Upload embedded in the ImageBrowser.
                    $(".k-imagebrowser .k-upload").find("input").data("kendoUpload").bind("select", 
                      function (e) {
                        // Prevent the event if the selected file is not of specified extension.
                        if (e.files[0].extension.toLowerCase() != ".jpg" && e.files[0].extension.toLowerCase() != ".jpeg" && e.files[0].extension.toLowerCase() != ".png" && e.files[0].extension.toLowerCase() != ".gif") {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            $("<div></div>").kendoAlert({
                                title: false,
                                content: "The file extension is not *.png,*.gif,*.jpg,*.jpeg.",
                                buttonLayout: "normal"
                            }).data("kendoAlert").open();
                        }

                        var s = e.files[0].size / Math.pow(1000, 2);
                        //Size validation
                        if (s > 5) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            $("<div></div>").kendoAlert({
                                title: false,
                                content: "File size should not be more than 5 MB",
                                buttonLayout: "normal"
                            }).data("kendoAlert").open();
                        }

                        $('.k-reset.k-floats.k-tiles.k-widget.k-listview.k-selectable').children('li').each(function (index, value) {
                            // Prevent the event if the selected file is already exist.
                            if ($(this).children("strong").html() == e.files[0].name) {
                                e.preventDefault();
                                $("<div></div>").kendoAlert({
                                    title: false,
                                    content: "A file with name already exists in the current directory",
                                    buttonLayout: "normal"
                                }).data("kendoAlert").open();
                            }
                        });

                    });
                    //Delete image from image browser
                    $(".k-toolbar-wrap>.k-button-icon").click(function (event) {
                        var type;
                        var name;
                        if ($(this).children().hasClass("k-i-close")) {
                            //alert();
                            //event.preventDefault();
                            event.stopPropagation();
                            var path = "";
                            var img;
                            $('.k-breadcrumbs-wrap').children('a').each(function (index, value) {
                                if ($(this).hasClass("k-link")) {
                                    path = path + $(this).text() + "/";
                                }
                            });

                            $('.k-reset.k-floats.k-tiles.k-widget.k-listview.k-selectable').children('li').each(function (index, value) {
                                if ($(this).hasClass("k-tile k-state-selected")) {
                                    img = $(this).attr("data-uid");
                                    type = $(this).attr("data-type");
                                    name = $(this).children("strong").html();
                                }
                            });
                            //alert(path);
                            window.OpenDeleteConfirm("Are you sure you want to delete this record?").then(function (e) {
                                $.ajax({
                                    type: 'POST',
                                    url: "/ImageBrowser/Destroy",
                                    data: { "path": path, "type": type, "name": name },
                                    success: function (response) {
                                        //$(".k-reset.k-floats.k-tiles.k-widget.k-listview.k-selectable>.k-tile.k-state-selected").remove();
                                    }
                                }); 
                            }, function () {
                                // window.myalert("You chose to Cancel action.");
                            });
                        }
                        else {

                        }

                    });

                    //End 
                });
            });

        }```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, kendoEditor has an internal [ImageBrowser](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/editor/configuration/imagebrowser) that has an internal ListView with the files that keeps the list of files in its dataSource, that it creates from your `transport`  configuration. Your ajax call doesn't tell that dataSource that an item should be removed.

Since it's a poorly documented component of [Kendo Professional](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-ui/comparison), I suggest you file a ticket with Telerik.

Comment: Can you please suggest if there is any way to access that list

Comment: Something like `$(".k-filebrowser-dialog .k-listview").data("kendoListView")` ? It's hackish and can break if Kendo changes the internals.

Comment: or how can i call read method of image browser because i think that could solve my problem.....in image browser i can create folders too and upload images on the particular folder so if i delete some images move to one folder than come back the image is deleted....because everytime we enter a folder read method is called ......and my problem is only occurs if i delete image and upload new image or craete new folder that old image will be shown but this will not be the problem if move back and forth a folder

Comment: Once you have the ListView, just do `listView.dataSource.read()`

Comment: i try your suggested approach and call read method then refresh the listview and it works perfectly .....Thanks a lot :) I had tried many more other way since days but failed.... you save my day ...thanks.....